# Ubuntu 18.04 - Unable to chown ext4 network drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, nas

I have a nested VM running Ubuntu Server 18.04 (mounted via Virtual Machine Manager - KVM). I am unable to change ownership and permissions on a network drive in a Synology server.

The drive is mounted via `fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.11/Seedbox /mnt/Seedbox ext4 username=****,password=****,rw,iocharset=utf8, 0 0
```

I´m unable to chown the mounting point `/mnt/Seedbox` to give ownership to `debian-transmission` so that transmission can write to the disk.

I tried mounting it as CIFS -> same problem.
The drives are in a Synology Hybrid RAID and the file system is shown as ext4 on the sylogy web admin site.

I don't understand what the problem is here, `chown`, `chgrp` and `chmod` all seem to not change anything, but don´t throw an error/warning.

The command `ls -l /mnt/Seedbox` returns :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 14 21:44 Seedbox
```

Comment: Is the type of the filesystem really `ext4` in `fstab`? And it works? The rest looks like `cifs`. What does `mount` say?

Comment: permissions on host ?

Comment: (1) If the command `ls -l /mnt/Seedbox` reports information about a directory called `Seedbox`, then that means that you are looking at `/mnt/Seedbox/Seedbox`.  Can you clarify? (2) Is “sylogy” a typo for “Synology”?

Comment: Why is the third field ext4?  That does not make sense in context of the fstable (first field) which implies a CIFS mount.   If you are using a CIFS mount you may need to map permissions using uid=XXX,gid=XXX